# Pandas: convert unicode strings to string

Tags: python, pandas

I have data frame and there are 2 columns with unicode value. I need to convert it to string. I try `df.domain.astype(str)` but it return unicode strings.
How can I do that?
Data looks like (I need to convert either columns)

```
domain       search_term
vk.com           None
facebook.com     None
yandex.ru        снять квартиру
locals.ru        None
yandex.ru        снять квартиру без посредников в Москве
avito.ru         None
```

Comment: Sorry are you asking for `df['str_col'].str.decode('utf-8')`? Also can you post raw data and code to avoid ambiguity

Comment: @EdChum it doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

Would this help?:

```
for col in types[types=='unicode'].index:
    df[col] = df[col].astype(str)
```

or:

```
for col in types[types=='unicode'].index:
     df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: x.encode('utf-8').strip())
```

Comment: Can you say, can I use it in this string? `f.edge(group['subdomain'].iloc[i], group['subdomain'].iloc[i+1]`